# Dynamic media query to display @2x images

Tags: php, html, css, retina-display

I have two thumbnail image versions for @1x and @2x displays:

@1x: `/img/path/to/file.jpg`

@2x: `/img/path/to/file@2x.jpg`

From inspecting a website that does what I want, I have replicated the HTML:

```
<div 
data-src="/<?php echo preg_replace("/(.+)\.(.+)/","$1@2x.$2",$item["thumb"]); ?>" 
data-media="(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2), (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), (min-resolution: 1.5dppx)">
</div>

<img data-toggle="modal" onclick="return false" data-target="#image-modal" class="thumbnail" src="/<?php echo $item['thumb']; ?>">
```

When a user has a HiDPI display, I want them to see the `@2x` version. The `img` stores the @1x image, the `div` stores the @2x image src in `data-src` along with the required media query. Basically, based on the media query, I want to replace the img src (I think) with the @2x version.

However, I have no idea how to do this, as I was only inspecting the website at its surface.